# IP адреса, шлюзы и DNS

Tags: сеть, ip, dns

У меня чисто теоретический вопрос. Мы с коллегой пользуемся двумя компьютерами на работе, и сис админы выдали нам определенные IP адреса, DNS и шлюзы для подключения к интернету. Маска подсети общая 255.255.255.0. Вопрос в том, могут ли возникать проблемы с соединением у кого либо из нас, если IP адреса разные, а шлюз и DNS одинаковый? Или при разных IP адресах они друг от друга не зависят?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не будет проблем.
ДНС вообще может быть у всех одинаковый - это сервер к которому компьютер обращается для определения адресов.

Шлюз - это узел, через который вы, грубо говоря, выходите "наружу" из вашей сети. Т.е. если вы в одной сети, то он у вас одинаковый. Так и должно быть.